# A generic list of records that contains dynamic array

Tags: arrays, delphi, generics, record, tlist

I have a generic list of records. these records contains a dynamic array like following

```
Type
  TMyRec=record
MyArr:Array of Integer;
    Name: string;
    Completed: Boolean;
  end;

var
  MyList:TList<TMyRec>;
  MyRec:TMyRec;
```

then I create the list and set the array length like followings

```
MyList:=TList<TMyRec>.Create;
SetLength(MyRec.MyArr,5);
MyRec.MyArr[0]:=8;  // just for demonstration
MyRec.Name:='Record 1';
MyRec.Completed:=true;
MyList.Add(MyRec);
```

then i change the data in `MyArr` and i also change `MyRec.Name` and add another item to the list

```
MyRec.MyArr[0]:=5;  // just for demonstration
MyRec.Name:='Record 2';
MyRec.Completed:=false;
MyList.Add(MyRec);
```

when `MyRec.MyArr` changes after adding the first item to the list, `MyArr` which is stored to the list also changes. however the other record fields does not.

My question is how to prevent the changes in `MyRec.MyArr` to be reflected on the array which is already stored in the list item.

do i need to declare multiple records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example can be simplified like so, removing all reference to generics:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  x, y: array of Integer;

begin
  SetLength(x, 1);
  x[0] := 42;
  y := x;
  Writeln(x[0]);
  y[0] := 666;
  Writeln(x[0]);
end.
```

The output is:

```
42
666
```

The reason for this is that a dynamic array is a reference type. When you assign to a variable of dynamic array type, you are taking another reference and not making a copy.

You can resolve this by forcing a reference to be unique (that is have just a simple reference). There are a number of ways to achieve this. For instance, you can call `SetLength` on the array that you want to be unique.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  x, y: array of Integer;

begin
  SetLength(x, 1);
  x[0] := 42;
  y := x;
  SetLength(y, Length(y));
  Writeln(x[0]);
  y[0] := 666;
  Writeln(x[0]);
end.
```

Output:

```
42
42
```

So, in your code you can write it like this:

```
MyList:=TList<TMyRec>.Create;

SetLength(MyRec.MyArr,5);
MyRec.MyArr[0]:=8;  // just for demonstration
MyRec.Name:='Record 1';
MyRec.Completed:=true;
MyList.Add(MyRec);

SetLength(MyRec.MyArr,5); // <-- make the array unique
MyRec.MyArr[0]:=5;  // just for demonstration
MyRec.Name:='Record 2';
MyRec.Completed:=false;
MyList.Add(MyRec);
```

You can use a variety of other ways to enforce uniqueness, including `Finalize`, assigning `nil`, `Copy`, etc.

This issue is covered in some detail in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays). Here are the pertinent excerpts:

> If X and Y are variables of the same dynamic-array type, X := Y points
>   X to the same array as Y. (There is no need to allocate memory for X
>   before performing this operation.) Unlike strings and static arrays,
>   copy-on-write is not employed for dynamic arrays, so they are not
>   automatically copied before they are written to. For example, after
>   this code executes:
>
> ```
>  var
>    A, B: array of Integer;
>    begin
>      SetLength(A, 1);
>      A[0] := 1;
>      B := A;
>      B[0] := 2;
>    end;
> ```
>
> the value of A[0] is 2. (If A and B were static arrays, A[0] would
>   still be 1.) Assigning to a dynamic-array index (for example,
>   MyFlexibleArray[2] := 7) does not reallocate the array. Out-of-range
>   indexes are not reported at compile time. In contrast, to make an
>   independent copy of a dynamic array, you must use the global Copy
>   function:
>
> ```
>  var
>    A, B: array of Integer;
>  begin
>    SetLength(A, 1);
>    A[0] := 1;
>    B := Copy(A);
>    B[0] := 2; { B[0] <> A[0] }
>  end;
> ```

Comment: +1, I'm curious why there is no straight forward language element to make a deep copy. `Clone()` would be a good name. Or introduce COW dynamic arrays (which I already have).

Comment: @LURD Deep copy is one of things that is easy to say, but very hard to do. At a language level you'd need every single type to be able to perform deep copy. What would that mean for a pointer? Perhaps a typed pointer is doable, but what about untyped pointer? How do you deep copy an interface? So I think it is intrinsically hard. Thanks for the uv btw. Voting here is odd I must say. More votes for the non-answer.

Comment: @lurd maybe because strings consist of simple chars, but arrays can consist of objects, interfaces and who knows what. It would be hiding the complexity leading to even failed expectations like the one starting this topic.

Comment: For strings, interfaces and likes, just increase the reference count. Untyped pointers would be left in the wild, but would not differ from the Copy() command.

Comment: @LURD That would not be a deep copy. Deep copy implies copying values.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because it's hard, that's exactly why it's such a cop out that the VCL has a copy function but not a deep copy function. You program in Python, so you know Python doesn't shirk from providing a deep copy function. Just because there are some corner cases in Delphi doesn't mean a deep copy function shouldn't exist. There are some metadata Python's deep copy doesn't copy either. And yes, every single type should be able to perform a deep copy - and serialization while they're at it.

Comment: @Arioch'The Other languages don't shirk away from deep copy. In fact, the unusual behavior would not be from a deep copy function, but from David's own example where the array implicitly performs a copy-on-write when the SetLength function is performed. That's a violation of principle of least astonishment in my mind from a language design perspective.

Comment: @alcalde Python types do need to implement hooks for deepcopy to work. The hooks are well defined, but they need cooperation from the actors.

Answer (score 4):

*...here were observations of the original question controverscies*

What for the rest, i'd prefer to break the link between your variable and the list immediately after you put added the value. In few months you would forgot that issue you had and maybe would refactor your program. If you put the 2nd `SetLength` away from `List.Add` you may just forget that the record still holds a reference to the same array you have in the list.

```
  TMyRec=record
    MyArr: TArray< double >; // making it 1D for simplicity
    Name: string;
    Completed: Boolean;
  end;


SetLength(MyRec.MyArr,5);
MyRec.MyArr[0]:=8;  // just for demonstration
MyRec.Name:='Record 1';
MyRec.Completed:=true;
MyList.Add(MyRec);
MyRec.MyArr := nil; // breaking the parasite link immediately!
```

...now here you can do anything you want - but MyRec is already clean.

Then, what if you would have many arrays, not just one ? There is one function that Delphi uses itself behind the curtains: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Finalize which would have find all the arrays to clean.

```
SetLength(MyRec.MyArr,5);
MyRec.MyArr[0]:=8;  // just for demonstration
MyRec.Name:='Record 1';
MyRec.Completed:=true;
MyList.Add(MyRec);
Finalyze(MyRec); // breaking all the parasite links immediately!
```

Now, the last option would just to compact the used code into a procedure, that you would be able to call several times. Then the variable would become local one and Delphi would `Finalize` it for you automatically.

```
Procedure AddRec( const Name: string; const Compl: boolean; const Data: array of double);
var i: integer; MyRec: TMyRec;
begin
  SetLength(MyRec.MyArr, Length( Data ) );
  for i := 0 to Length(Data) - 1 do
    MyRec.MyArr[i] := Data [i];  

  MyRec.Name := Name;

  MyRec.Completed := Compl;
  MyList.Add(MyRec);
end;

MyList:=TMyList<TMyRec>.create;

AddRec( 'Record 1', True , [ 8 ]);
AddRec( 'Record 2', False, [ 5 ]);
...
```

Since `MyRec` is now a local variable, that gets destroyed when exiting from `AddRec` it would not hold that link to the array and would not conduse neither you nor any other fellow developer, who would use your types.

Comment: I just fixed the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but you don't know what the topic starter actually meant. Two parts contradict each other and you took the liberty to decide on your own WHICH one was wrong. I could see it worth it, if he abandoned stack overflow, so there would be a point in making the question benefitting to anyone rather than benefitting to fleed TS. However TS is here and he can fix the question in the direction that really is his intention.

Comment: it is my mistake. `MyArr: array of integer` is the correct decleration. Question is modified by David

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ccan you add nil, finalyze and local var into your answer ? then mine can be deleted

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  mmm, mentioning them "they exists" is not showing examples and explaining cons and pros. Cannot agree you already did it :-) and local vars are not even mentioned. Neither is breaking the link immediately.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer if you don't like it. In the meantime, I will attempt to enumerate every single possible solution to this problem so that I can write full demonstrations of them.

Comment: I also don't understand why you criticise my answer for supposed incompleteness. You don't even explain the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i started that as a detailed comment on the problems in the Q. Then i added few examples cnotinuing from the point where you stopped. It was not intended as a full answer, so that is why i want to fuse them

Comment: Go ahead and do so if you wish

Answer (score -1):

Just create a new one into old variable, every thing should be Ok,

```
MyList:=TList<TMyRec>.Create;
SetLength(MyRec.MyArr,5);
MyRec.MyArr[0]:=8;  // just for demonstration
MyRec.Name:='Record 1';
MyRec.Completed:=true;
MyList.Add(MyRec);

MyRec := TMyRec.Create();
SetLength(MyRec.MyArr,5);

MyRec.MyArr[0]:=5;  // just for demonstration
MyRec.Name:='Record 2';
MyRec.Completed:=false;
MyList.Add(MyRec);
```

Comment: TMyRec is a record. It has no Create method. And an answer with no explanation is never ideal. Programming should be about understanding rather than magic incantations.